# JS Bookmarklet AJAX request generates error: Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I built a bookmarklet like Pinterest where I can save images from a website, and after injecting my Js in the webpage I need to call via ajax a php file but some websites (very few actually) throw an error:

> Refused to connect to XXX because it violates the following Content
>   Security Policy directive: "connect-src...

I wonder if I can send some headers within my jquery ajax request?
how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you making the request to 3rd party sites with php or JavaScript? If it's with JavaScript you cannot do anything as it is up to the server to only allow same origin: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @HMR ok... i had same hunch...

Comment: If you are making the request from the client (using JavaScript) you can use your php server as a proxy. All requests from the clients are made to your server (same origin) and your server makes the request to 3rd party api's. You can use the proxy only as a backup when a request from client fails for certain sites with certain errors.